# Consider the arrangement,

Tags: combinatorics

Where we are interested in
*no of ways to arrange *the followings **in a row**

**(** EDIT- *Typing mistake in values so please go after* **EDIT** **)**

a) 7 '+''s & 4 '-''s such that '-''s dont appear side by side

*Answer-* ***⁷ C 4***

*what i did-*  was, To place '-''s in a way that 2 '-''s dont look together i placed **6**'+''s spacing from starting to end & between them: _ +
_+ _ + _ + _ + _ + _, so basically there i could find 7 *spaces* on which i can place 4'-''s, which is the correct answer!

B)5 Girls and 5 Boys so that no 2 girls adjacent=  4![for boys]x5![for girls]

C) 10 boys & 10 girls such that no girl appear side by side-**

**Answer**: 11!x10!

here why cant we apply the same logic from **a)**? If we apply it goes like: there will be 11 spaces for 10 girls if we arrange 10 boys by spaces as done in **a)**, so 10 girls can be fitted in 11 places should be 11***C***10!

*Despite similarities of questions there is no sign of patterns in answers. Is there anything more needs to be equipped to see the 'Pattern'?*

**

- **EDIT**

**

a) 6 '+''s & 4 '-''s such that '-''s dont appear side by side

*Answer-* ***⁷ C 4***

*what i did-*  was, To place '-''s in a way that 2 '-''s dont look together i placed **6**'+''s spacing from starting to end & between them: _ +
_+ _ + _ + _ + _ + _, so basically there i could find 7 *spaces* on which i can place 4'-''s, which is the correct answer!

**BUT**

b) 10 boys & 10 girls such that no girl appear side by side-**

**Answer**: 11!x10!

here why cant we apply the same logic from **a)**? If we apply it goes like: there will be 11 spaces for 10 girls if we arrange 10 boys by spaces as done in **a)**, so 10 girls can be fitted in 11 places should be 11***C***10!

*Despite similarities of questions there is no sign of patterns in answers. Is there anything more needs to be equipped to see the 'Pattern'?*

Comment: Please explain your reasoning rather than just stating a formula.  If you explain your reasoning, it will be easier for people reading your question to identify any errors you may have made.  For instance, $\binom{7}{4}$ is the number of ways or arranging seven addition signs and four negative signs in a row, not the number of ways of arranging the same objects so no two negative signs are adjacent.

Comment: It's 6 '+'s actually! See, i've edited.

Comment: By changing the question after it was answered, you invalidated the answer that true blue anil wrote.

Comment: "Correcting" may be more preferable word! Well, he himself countered mistakes which i took seriously to replicate, so that my doubt can be seen in more viable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental difference in the two cases is the fact that **all +'s are identical and all -'s are identical** but each boy are is different. So is each girl. No one boy is exactly the same as any other boy. So an arrangement is required in the second case.

@true pointed out this fact already, but I think you misunderstood what he/she meant.

Hence, in the first case, you correctly deduced that considering 7 gaps between every plus _ + _ + _ + _ + _ + _ + _ we get the answer as $^7C_4$

Similarly, in the second case, considering 11 gaps between 10 boys, _ B _ B _ B _ B _ B _ B _ B _ B _ B _ B _, the first step towards the answer gives us $^{11}C_{10}$

However, ***its not over yet***...

Since *each boy is distinct and each girl is distinct* they can arrange *among themselves* to give rise to a different arrangement, which is *not the case with +'s or with -'s* as **every + is the same as every other +, but every boy is not the same as every other boy.**

Hence, to the above obtained answer we mutiply one $10!$ for girls and another $10!$ for boys.

Thus, Required Answer $= ^{11}C_{10} \times 10! \times 10! = \frac{11!}{1! \times 10!} \times 10! \times 10! = 11! \times 10!$, which is the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers appear wrong to start with, so it is no wonder that patterns can't be seen !

$5$ boys and $5$ girls: $-B-B-B-B-B-$

The girls can be *positioned* in the gaps in $\binom65 = 6$ ways, and permuted in $5!$ ways, so the answer should be $6\times5!5!\;\; or\;\; 6!5!$

The second answer is also wrong.
There are $8$ places available for the minuses, but since all minuses are identical (unlike the girls) the answer should be $\binom84$

$-plus-plus-plus-plus-plus-plus-plus-$

I hope you can now see some pattern, and decide for yourself whether the last answer is right or wrong ?

Comment: Thanks for correcting. See, i've edited!

Comment: *You are not supposed to alter your questions and answers after an answer has been received. Part A has been removed, and numbers in part B have been changed .* $\quad\quad\quad$To answer the query at the end of your altered question, B and C approaches differ because in B, the pluses and minuses are indistinguishable, whereas in C, the boys and girls are distinguishable

Comment: I realised my mistake, Pardon please! But i dont get this where you said pluses and minuses are identical! Like boys and girls, +'s & -'s also are different.

Comment: My doubt is resolved, thank you for all the effort!

Comment: All pluses are identical, all minuses are identical. In contrast, all boys are different, all girls are different, ie each has a separate identity.

Comment: thank you! @true blue anil